# How to setup mutli-tenancy using row level security on Postgres with knex

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, knex.js, objection.js

I am architecting a database where I expected to have 1,000s of tenants where some data will be shared between tenants. I am currently planning on using Postgres with row level security for tenant isolation. I am also using knex and Objection.js to model the database in node.js.

Most of the tutorials I have seen look like [this](https://github.com/franzon/postgres-rls-example/blob/master/src/utils/tenantDatabaseManager.js#L33) where you create a separate knex connection per tenant. However, I've run into a problem on my development machine where after I create ~100 connections, I received this error: "remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections".

I'm investigating a few possible solutions/work-arounds, but I was wondering if anyone has been able to make this setup work the way I'm intending. Thanks!

Comment: That won't work so well with that many database users. You'll have to redesign.

Comment: A generic way of achieving RLS https://saravanandorai.blogspot.com/2022/04/implementing-row-level-security-rls-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one solution might be to cache a limited number of connections, and destroy the oldest cached connection when the limit is reached.   See [this code](https://github.com/awais-shafiq/knex_pg_rls/blob/429e7dd28d2cd710fb6f6778d5401fdcdeb6c337/backend/clock/database/DatabaseConfig.js#L6) as an example.

That code should probably be improved, however, to use a Map as the `knexCache` instead of an object, since a Map remembers the insertion order.

Comment: That is a very good idea. Thank you!